# how to test the JSonResult in xunit test case?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, xunit.net

I am doing unit testing with xunit (ASP.NET MVC).
I have written Action in controller which returns JsonResult.
For returning JsonResult, in Action I have written:

```
return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Login") });
```

For testing the action, I have written in unit test case as:

```
JsonResult jsonResult = _accountController.ForgotPassword(ValidUserName) as JsonResult;
Assert.Equal("{ ok = true, newurl = Url.Action('Login') }", jsonResult.Data.ToString());
```

But, it's not working. Please guide me to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest debugging your unit test and looking at the value returned by `jsonResult.Data.ToString()`. My guess is `newurl` doesn't contain what you think it does. Assuming you're using VS2013 you can easily debug a unit test by setting a breakpoint, right-click inside the test method body, and select Debug Tests.

An alternative approach to verifying the information is to cast the JsonResult.Data to a dynamic. This allows you to compare each property individually instead of stringifying the JSON and comparing the results. This approach is, in my opinion, cleaner when the JSON becomes larger than a few properties.

```
var dynData = (dynamic)jsonResult.Data;
Assert.IsTrue( (bool)dynData.ok );
Assert.AreEqual( Url.Action("Login"), (string)dynData.newurl );
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I debug the controller and its giving me nullreferenceexception for "return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("Login") });" and debugger is not coming back to testcontroller. But, code is running for this.